# Reading Excel SheetData with OpenXml returns null

Tags: c#, .net, excel, openxml

I'm trying to read a fairly simple Excel spreadheet (saved as an xlsx) using the [OpenXML nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml).

I'm able to locate the specific `Sheet` I'm interested in, but calling `sheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>()` on it, in order to access the cell values, always returns `null`.  I've looked at several examples online, and they all seem to agree that this is the correct way to access the data.

The xlsx file I'm trying to read can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1frkQHID1nZssRaup2m5NKIsZdGc2Yg-p/view?usp=sharing).
[image]

Here is the code I'm using to read the file. The line `var data = sheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();` is where the `null` is returned.

```
void Main()
{
    using (var s = System.IO.File.OpenRead("c:\\ImportTemplate.xlsx"))
    using (var document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(s, false))
    {
        foreach (var worksheetPart in document.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts)
        {
            Sheet sheet = GetSheetFromWorkSheet(document.WorkbookPart, worksheetPart);
            var name = sheet.Name.Value;
            if (name == "ImportData")
            {
                var data = sheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>(); // <-- data is set to null
                foreach (var row in data.Descendants<Row>()){
                    // [...]
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

public static Sheet GetSheetFromWorkSheet(WorkbookPart workbookPart, WorksheetPart worksheetPart)
{
    string relationshipId = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart);
    IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.Sheets.Elements<Sheet>();
    return sheets.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id.HasValue && s.Id.Value == relationshipId);
}
```

The above code as an easily runnable LINQPad file can be downloaded from [here](http://share.linqpad.net/s3nrxg.linq).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change `sheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>()` to `worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>()`

Comment: Ahh, thank you!  OpenXML has so many objects with such similar names that its very hard for me to keep track of all the relationships between them.